# NameError: global name 'Player1_row' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

I wrote this tic tac toe game against AI (I am improving the AI right now):

```
Matrix = [[0, 0, 0], 
          [0, 0, 0], 
          [0, 0, 0]]
Matrix_2 = [[" ", " ", " "], 
            [" ", " ", " "], 
            [" ", " ", " "]]
def turnX():
    Player1_row = int(raw_input("P1 What row do you want?"))
    Player1_row = Player1_row - 1
    Player1_column = int(raw_input("P1 What column do you want?"))
    Player1_column = Player1_column - 1
    if Player1_row > Matrix:
        turnX()
    if Player1_column > Matrix:
        turnX()
    if (1 == Matrix[Player1_column][Player1_row] or 500 == Matrix[Player1_column][Player1_row]):
        print "This is an invaild move!"
        turnX()
    else:
        Matrix[Player1_column][Player1_row] = 1
        Matrix_2[Player1_column][Player1_row] = "X"

def turnY():
      global Player1_row
      Player2_row = int(random.randint(1, boardX))
      Player2_row = Player2_row - 1
      Player2_column = int(random.randint(Player1_row, boardY))
      Player2_column = Player2_column - 1
      if (1 == Matrix[Player2_column][Player2_row] or 500 == Matrix[Player2_column][Player2_row]):
          turnY()
      else:
          print "AI Turn:"
          Matrix[Player2_column][Player2_row] = 500
          Matrix_2[Player2_column][Player2_row] = "O"
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NameError: global name 'Player1_row' is not defined`.
```

I am trying to make the AI block the player's last move.

Comment: The variable `Player1_row` in the function `turnX()` is local. It is destroyed as soon as `turnX()` returns, and it is not accessible in `turnY()`. You may want to add `global Player1_row` in `turnX()`.

Comment: Python gave you a stack trace showing you which line had the problem. Please post that entire trace. Python told you, but then you expect us to dig through your code to find out where the problem is?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player1_row is not a global variable, but a local variable for the function turn_X.

To solve this, try setting Player1_row to a global variable in turn_X.